# C# wpf How to pass variable Excel.Worksheet from Button_Click to another Button_Click

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, worksheet-function

I'm writing C# WPF easy program for sorting specific columns in excel and I have a problem in passing variable excel.worksheet from Button_Click to another Button_Click. 
Code below:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Sorting
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        int column, CounterRow;
        string filepath;
        Excel.Worksheet x = new Excel.Worksheet();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Choose_Files_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Multiselect = false;
            ofd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
            ofd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                ListBox_Files.Items.Clear();
                filepath = ofd.FileName;
                ListBox_Files.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(filepath));

            }
            if (ListBox_Files.Items.Count != 0) ListBox_Files.IsEnabled = Otworz.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        private void Button_Click_0(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
            excel.Visible = true;
            excel.DisplayAlerts = false;

            Excel.Workbook sheet = excel.Workbooks.Open(filepath);
            Excel.Worksheet x = excel.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;

            MessageBox.Show("select column");

            Sort(x,1);

            MessageBox.Show("end");

            excel.Quit();
        }

        void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
            excel.Visible = true;
            excel.DisplayAlerts = false;

            Excel.Workbook sheet = excel.Workbooks.Open(filepath);
            Excel.Worksheet x = excel.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;

        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Sort(x, 1);
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           Sort(x, 2);
        }

        private void Sort(Excel.Worksheet excel, int info)
        {
            Excel.Range rng = excel.Application.ActiveCell;
            column = rng.Column;            

            Excel.Range userRange = excel.UsedRange;
            CounterRow = userRange.Rows.Count;

            Excel.Range range = excel.Range[excel.Cells[7, 1], excel.Cells[CounterRow - 1, 8]];

            if (info == 1) range.Sort(range.Columns[column], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending);
            else if (info == 2) range.Sort(range.Columns[column], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain me, why Click_Button_0 is working, and while I open the file thru Click_Button and then I will sort columns thru Click_Button_1 and Click Button_2 is not working not? Visual studio said : "System.InvalidCastException"

Comment: It's not working as you are typing to cast `x` to `Excel.Worksheet` type but in reality `x` can not be type cast to mentioned type. While doing debugging you can check the type of `x` and validate if 'x' can be converted to `Excel.Worksheet` type

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer :) But do you know how to solve this problem? How should I declare this variable, to make this works?

Comment: Never mind ;) I've just solved this problem :) 

I had to declare this in the begining of the main class:

        Excel.Worksheet x;
        Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();

Also I had to add : 

            Excel.Worksheet x = excel.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;

in the each Click_Button voids. 

I feagured it out when I read more carefully debugger :P